# if vertex array count > 1000, glDrawArrays becomes slow?

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl

I have painting app. Mouse event coordinates are stored to VertexArray. Then vertex array is being drawn to screen. My code structure looks like this

```
// I get mouse event coordinates and store them to VertexArray
glPushMatrix();
//some new matrix settings
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, framebuffer);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//now I draw first full size textured quad and later I draw vertexArray

glDrawArrays(.....);

//and now I draw second full size textured quad on top of first quad ant that what have been drawn from vertex array

glPopMatrix();
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);


//immediately after that I draw FBO to screen:
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbTexture);
//Code for drawing textured quad
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

So everything  is redrawn every time when new mouse event coordinate is being registered. And if there are more than 1000 coordinates, drawing becomes really slow. Where could be my problem? I thing 1000 vertices for OpenGL is not much

Comment: There's a huge difference between *batch size* and *geometry throughput*. For rendering to be performant a drawing batch should fit into the vertex attribute cache. Depending on your hardware, the cache may not be able to hold more than ~1000 vertices. Solution: Draw in multiple batches.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the number of vertices; it's how you're sending them.

First, you never defined "really slow"; often times people will mistakenly think that a change from 400fps to 300fps is "slow". It's not. It only represents a render time increase from 2.5ms-per-frame to 3.3ms, a change of less than a single millisecond. Non-trivial, but probably not something to be *too* concerned over.

It's always important to measure performance in terms of render time, not FPS.

That being said, your main problem is that you're drawing a single quad at a time. Each one coming from a separate `glDrawArrays` command. That's not necessarily a good thing, *especially* if you change state between drawing commands (like binding a texture and so forth).

If you're doing that, then you need to find ways to avoid doing that. What you want to do is render a lot of quads all with one draw calls. This means you have to use the same texture for all of them.

The common solution to this problem is to make a larger texture that has multiple images in different locations. This is commonly called a "texture atlas" (Google that for the details). Each quad would have texture coordinates for the particular image it renders. Text is often drawn in such a way, where each letter (glyph) is stored in the same texture.